# Callout using External Services: Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: visual-workflow, namedcredentials, external-services

The scenario is that want to send a simple JSON-message to a URI without any authentication. I want to achieve this without using code, so I am trying to use a combination of named credentials, external services and flow.

I am however receiving the following error:

`"AuthorizationFailed\",\"message\":\"The authentication credentials are not valid.\"}}","responseCode":"401"}|HttpResponseStatus:401`

This is fairly frustrating as there is no authentication to pass.

Am I missing some setting?

If you need additional info, let me know (everything but the endpoint can be found below)

```
Method=POST, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Not Set, Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, Request Size bytes=62, Retry o
```

Comment: If you're getting a 401, that means that the endpoint you're using does indeed want authentication. Make sure you have the correct endpoint, and check the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Service Schema for the External Service the path was adding a `/` to my URL. This was causing the authentication error